# equalizer on small-only does not exist in foundation 6?

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation-6

Im using Foundation 6, the last released version. 
I have a problem with equalizer. I want to equalizer to be turn on only for small screen. 
In according to : http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html , 
when I use this : 
`data-equalizer data-equalize-on="small"` 
it works on all screen sizes. 
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out answer of my question.
there is no built-in solution unlike foundation 5, so we have to limit the equalization by hand in css.
it will override equalization height for medium and larger viewports.
.custom-class must be written in all divs that you don't need to be equalized.

```
@media (min-width:640px){
    .custom-class{
        height:auto !important; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `in all divs that you need to be equalized` ?

Comment: you need to just give all wanted dives .custom-class and they won't be equalized anymore for screens larger than small.

Answer (score 1):

You could change that to `data-equalize-on="small-only"`

Comment: this is for previous version of foundation.
after lots of googling this problem, I found out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

just adding to the solution. if you us "small", it means from small and up. You have to make sure to include "small only" and then let Equalizer do it's magic.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone landing on this page with similar questions, please note Foundation 5 has media queries for the `data-equalizer` functionality. If you look at [Foundation Responsive equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/equalizer.html#responsive-equalizer), you can do:

`<... data-equalizer data-equalizer-mq="small-only">`

to apply to small screens only. This was really useful for me!